# how to put query string in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, curl, retrofit2

Hi I need to implement this CURL code in Retrofit 2 in android :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=myname&password=mypass");
```

I used Retrofit like this :

```
Call<ResponseBody> login(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

but the target API just accepts post data to be a string like `"username=myname&password=mypass"`, not distinct parameters. 
How can I implement CURL code above, with Retrofit 2 ?

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Answer (score 0):

use @Field instead of @query and add @FormUrlEncoded at the beginning of your Call method

Comment: does it show any error, have you tried calling the api using postman tool in the browser?Check that you have given permission for internet in manifest

Comment: yes. I tested it by php curl, when data is a single string it works, but when data is an array, the API doesn't recognize the parameters.

Comment: I dont think the problem is with the retrofit code please check with your script

Comment: I don't need urlencoded data, I need a single string

Answer (score 0):

Probably can help someone with the same problem.
Use `@QueryName` can put query string.

```java
Call<ResponseBody> login(@QueryName String queryString);
```

Maybe need to replace some character and add `Interceptor`.
Refer:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199#issuecomment-307176224